# Regex for getting different formated locationnames and values

Tags: c#, regex

i am currently working on an tool to get both the location name and the value (I to VI) at the end of the string.Being an absolute Beginner at regex iam facing some trouble.

My current try:

```
 ^[A-Za-züäöÜÄÖ()-]*.(?!I)(?!V)[A-Za-züäöÜÄÖ.]*.(?!I)(?!V)[A-Za-züäöÜÄÖ.)]*.(?!I)(?!V)[A-Za-zü.äöÜÄÖ)ß.-]*
```

Example Strings and expected values:

```
"Apolda II" -> "Apolda", "II"
"Bad Isen II" -> "Bad Isen" "II"
"Hude (Oldenburg) II" -> "Hude (Oldenburg)" "II"
"Saale-Holzland-Kreis II" -> "Saale-Holzland-Kreis" "II"
"Brandenburg a. d. Havel I" -> "Brandenburg a. d. Havel" "I"
"Bad Lauterberg im Harz I" -> "Bad Lauerberg im Harz" "I"
```

I really stumble on getting all these cases checked. I would really appreciate any kind of help :).

Comment: Maybe you can just use [`Regex.Split(s, @"\s+(?=[XILCDM]+$)")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%2b%28%3f%3d%5bXILCDM%5d%2b%24%29&i=Apolda+II&o=m)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you must use Regex, I would propose simplier solution:

Let's say you have string `myStr = "Apolda II";`.

Since the number is always last "word", just split the whole string with space as separator:
`string[] strTable = myStr.Split(' ');`. Then your desired result be (`n = strTable.Length`): location = `strTable[1] + ... + strTable[n - 1]` and the value = `strTable[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

you may keep it simple, since you know it should be I - VI at end (roman numbers, right?) you can make an regex expecting everything before roman numbers

```
^(.*)\s+(I{1,3}|IV|V|VI)$
```

You must handle this as multi-line though.

```
new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(
    @"^(.*)\s+(I{1,3}|IV|V|VI)$",         
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline
).Matches("Apolda II\nBad Isen II")
```